# Creating audio level meter - signal normalization

Tags: audio, signal-processing, normalization

I have program which tracks audio signal in real time. Every processed sample I am able to read value of it in range between <-1, 1>.

I would like to create(and later display) audio level meter. From what I understand - to do it I need to keep converting my audio signal in real time, on each channel to dB and then display dB values on each channel in some graphical form of bars.

I am a bit lost how to do it and it should be simple matter. Would just normalization from <-1, 1> to <0, 1> (like... [n-sample +1]/2) and then calculating 20*log10 from each upcoming sample make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't plot the signal directly, as it always varying positive and negative.

Therefore you need to average out the strength of the signal every so many samples.

Say you're sampling at 44.1kHz, perhaps you might choose 4410 samples so you're updating your display 10 times per second.

So you calculate the RMS of your 4410 samples - see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square

The RMS value is always positive.

You can then convert this to Db:

dBV = 20 x log10(Vrms)

This assumes that your maximum signal -1 to +1 corresponds to -1 to +1 volt.  You will need to do further adjustments if not.

Comment: The result of the equation above is not strictly dBV, as that is a the relative measurement to a signal of 1V. The equation above calculates signal power relative to full-scale deflection, which in this case the clip point.

Audio level meters (especially with digital audio) sometimes show peak values rather than RMS, in which case you'd calculate  `max(abs(X0)...abs(Xn-1))` for each analysis window.

Comment: How would that work then? Calculate X = max(abs(X0)...abs(Xn-1)) from for example last 4410 samples and display 20 x log10(X) on lvl meter every 100ms?